# How can I get the virtual address of a shared library by the use of computer architecture state?

Tags: shared-libraries, memory-address, cpu-architecture, virtual-address-space

I am using a computer architecture simulator. I want to get the virtual address of a shared library of a program. What I can get from the simulator is computer architecture state, such as registers.

Can I do some math to get the virtual address of a shared library given a specified shared library name?

Comment: Can you post more details like the architecture of the machine being simulated? Is there an OS running?

Comment: the os is linux, the simulated machine is armv8.

Comment: if you know other systems ' methods, that is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that worked for me was to take a look at the java virtual machine source code. They catch the errors that occur when you call a native library and print all the stack, registers and what is available. I don't remember the details and you cannot use the code for commercial purposes but it is a great start.